# How to receive File in [FromBody] ASP.NET CORE 2 & Angular 5

Tags: angular, file-upload, asp.net-core, angular5

I want to send file image from my Angular 5 Reactive form to my ASP.NET 
so far I did this :

my Angular:

**Organization Interface:**

```
export interface Organization {
    id: number;
    organizationName: string;
    legalName: string;
    logoUrl: string;
    logoFile: any;
    ....
}
```

**organization.form.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="save()" class="form-horizontal">
  ...
  <div class="form-group  required" [ngClass]="{'has-error': editForm.get('legalName').touched && editForm.get('legalName').hasError('required')}">
    <label class="col-sm-2" for="legalName">Legal/Trading Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Legal/Trading Name" formControlName="legalName">
      <span class="help-block" *ngIf="editForm.get('legalName').touched && editForm.get('legalName').hasError('required')">Legal/Trading Name is required</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group  required" [ngClass]="{'has-error': editForm.get('logoUrl').touched && editForm.get('logoUrl').hasError('required')}">
    <label class="col-sm-2" for="logoUrl">Logo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="logoFile" placeholder="Logo" (change)="showPreviewImage($event)">
      <img [src]="localUrl" width="150" *ngIf="localUrl" class="imagePlaceholder">
      <input type="hidden" name="fileHidden" formControlName="logoUrl" />
      <!-- Validation Field -->

      <span class="help-block" *ngIf="editForm.get('logoUrl').touched && editForm.get('logoUrl').hasError('required')">Logo is required</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**organization-form.component.ts**

```js
// i want to display a upload image so I put on localImg

showPreviewImage(event: any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.localImg= reader.result;

      this.editForm.patchValue({
        logoUrl: file.name,
        logoFile: reader.result,
      });
      this.editForm.markAsDirty();
    }
  }

}
```

when save button clicked :

```js
save() {
  this.onSubmit.emit(this.editForm.value); 
}
```

Next I send to my asp.net core 2 server with HttpClient:

```js
create(org: Organization) {
  return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'organization/create', org);
}
```

I send the image and the data and I can see on my chrome inspect network:
[image: data sent to asp.net server]

While on server controller:

```
[HttpPost("create")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrganization([FromBody] OrganizationDto orgDto)
        {
            // check the same name of organization
            if (await _orgRepo.OrganizationExist(orgDto.OrganizationName))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("OrganizationName", "Organization Name already exists");
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            var orgToCreate = _mapper.Map<Organization>(orgDto);
            var file = orgDto.LogoFile;
            if(file != null) {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(this.logosFolderPath, FileMode.Create))  
                {  
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);  
                    orgToCreate.LogoUrl = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    throw new Exception(orgDto.LogoUrl);
                }  
            }
            // var createdOrg = await _orgRepo.CreateOrganization(orgToCreate);
            // var orgToReturn = _mapper.Map<OrganizationDetailedDto>(createdOrg);

            // return Ok(orgToReturn);
            return Ok(orgDto);
        }
```

my OrganizationDto:

```
public class OrganizationDto
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LegalName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LogoUrl { get; set; }
        public IFormFile LogoFile {get;set;}
```

but when I debug this, the variabel orgDto is null (not initialized or receiving data from angular). If I set the logoFile to blank in Angular, it work... but when I put file in it ... it doesnt work.

Any idea how to handle this ? I read the web we cannot use multipart/form-data in form ... i still have no idea about this. please help. thank you

Comment: To send a file via JSON it must be either a JavaScript array of bytes or a Base64-encoded string. I'm not familiar enough with Angular to tell you how to get there, but that should be easy enough to figure out. On the ASP.NET Core side, you'll need to bind to a property of type `byte[]`, not `IFormFile`, the latter is only for `multipart/form-data` encoded post bodies.

Comment: i use IFormFile because i read microsoft docs about uploading file in dotnet core but their example using razor pages

Comment: Yeah, where they're posting via a traditional HTML form (encoded as multipart/form-data). You're not doing it that way so it needs to be a byte[].

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your Http call is a bit simplified.
Try adding the Content-Type:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token' // if you have one
  })
};

addOrganization (org: Organization): Observable<Organization> {
  return this.httpClient.post<Organization>(this.heroesUrl, org, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addOrganization ', org))
    );
}
```

Then you call it by subscribing to it, something along these lines:

```
this.addOrganization(org).subscribe(
  (data: any) => {
     console.log(data, 'returned data');
  },
  (error: any) => {
     console.error(error, 'error received');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience you can't send file data as normal Json request. For that you have to use Form Data. Then your request will look like this:

```
let formToPost = new FormData();
//stringify your normal request
let requestToPost = JSON.stringify({id:1; organizationName: ABC; legalName: DEF}); 

formToPost .append("request", requestToPost);
formToPost .append("logoFile", YOUR_IMAGE_FILE);
```

Then in the controller level you can do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<YOUR_RESPON> AddTicketAsync(string request, List<IFormFile> logoFile)
{
  var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YOUR_TYPE>(request);
}
```

In here you can directly access your image file.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: is YOUR_IMAGE_FILE getting from
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    or should I use one with FileReader's result ?

Comment: You should be able to get it from, var file = event.target.files[0];

Comment: That's incorrect. The JSON member just needs to be a JavaScript array (of ints presenting the actual bytes) or a Base64-encoded string. ASP.NET Core can process either and will bind the result to a byte[].